# Deactivate user from the org

Tags: permissions, administration, user, deactivate

[image]

When I try to deactivate a user its showing like this, I already removed ownership in Lead, Opportunity , Account and Contact objects.

I need propper steps to accomplish that. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Please read [Error 'This user is the default owner of records created by guest users and can’t be deactivated'](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000381030&type=1) for more information. In summary, you need to go to each site in *Setup | Feature Settings | Digital Experiences | All Sites | Workspaces*, *Administration*, *Preferences*, then change the *Default Owner* field in the Record Ownership section. If the error still persists, you'll need to go to *Setup | User Interface | Sites and Domains | Sites | **Site Name** | Edit*, and change the *Default Record Owner*.

Comment: Mr. sfdcfox, There is no field called default owner , so How Can I do that

Comment: @PamodaWijesinghe You might not be on the correct screen. There definitely is a Default Record Owner field. You need to edit each Site individually.

Comment: Sir , I tried first method but in that screen showing another user ,so  its fine. then I tried to go with 2 method in that site there is no deault record owner field.
is that permission issue or something?

Comment: You only need to do the 2nd method (Sites) if the site is not a Community site.  If it is Community site (which you can see on the sites list), then there is no field and you have to use the 1st method.